# Getting object mismatch when setting PI DataLink function return equal to another variable

Tags: excel, vba, osisoft

I am attempting to print a series of ordered values to the current sheet based on change to a specific value provided by the PIDataLink current value function. I have bolded the area that is yielding a mismatch error, realizing that the rest of my code will share this error. (If MFA = "culstop" Then) 
*some repeat code is missing to save space.

```
Sub culturestop_timestamp()

Dim culstop As String
Dim MFA As Variant
Dim MFA2 As String    
Dim MFB As Variant
Dim MFC As Variant
Dim MFD As Variant
Dim MFE As Variant
Dim MFF As Variant
Dim MFG As Variant
Dim MFH As Variant
Dim start As Date
Dim curtime As Date
Dim rownum As Integer

Application.OnTime Now, "culturestop_timestamp"
reset:
    'Application.OnTime TimeValue("00:00:00", "culturestop_timestamp")
    start = Now()

rownum = 30

A = 0
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0
E = 0
F = 0
G = 0
H = 0


Do While curtime <= TimeValue("23:59:00")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"))

    MFA = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMA_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFB = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMB_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFC = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMC_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFD = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMD_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFE = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERME_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFF = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMF_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFG = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMG_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    MFH = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.MNFERMH_UNIT / PHASE_SELECT.CVS", 0, "")
    If A = 2 Then
        MFA = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If B = 2 Then
        MFB = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If C = 2 Then
        MFC = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If D = 2 Then
        MFD = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If E = 2 Then
        MFE = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If F = 2 Then
        MFF = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If G = 2 Then
        MFG = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If
    If H = 2 Then
        MFH = "Already_Brothed_Out_Today"
    End If

    ***If MFA = "culstop" Then***
        A = 2
        MFAR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE / MNFERMA_TYPE.CV", 0, "")
        MFAT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFAT
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFAR
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =


        rownum = rownum + 1

    End If

    If MFB = "culstop" Then
        B = 2
        MFBR = Application.Run("PICurrVal", "TAPS1.TC02_RECIPE / MNFERMB_TYPE.CV", 0, "")
        MFBT = Now()
        Sheet1.Range("A" & rownum) = MFBT
        Sheet1.Range("B" & rownum) = MFBR
        'Sheet1.Range("C" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("D" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("E" & rownum) =
        'Sheet1.Range("F" & rownum) =
        rownum = rownum + 1


    End If


    curtime = Now()

Loop
GoTo reset

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exact error message, and what's the value of MFA when it fails?

Comment: @TimWilliams Run-time error'13 Type mismatch. MFA has no value when it fails. At one point I was able to yield a string in MFA but I forgot how I did that.

Comment: When it errors, hit Debug and enter `Typename(MFA)` in the Immediate pane and hit enter - what output does that give you?

Comment: @TimWilliams MFA has the intended current value "CULTURE", My location tag was messed up. still getting the same error, looking at the bottom window, VBA lists my MFA variable as MFA(1) and MFA(2), the first being populated correctly, the second having no value.

Comment: If the value of MFA is "CULTURE" then that statement should not throw a type-mismatch error, so something else is going on here.  Not sure I follow the rest of your comment - are you saying that MFA is an array?  If so then that would be a problem...

Comment: MFA is not an array, it is just populated with whatever value it pulls from the server at that moment.

Comment: Then I'm not following where you're seeing MFA(1) and MFA(2). Might help to show the code for `PICurrVal`

Comment: PICurrVal is a function owned by OSIsoft. part of an excel add-in

Comment: It looks like all of my variables interacting with the PICurrVal function are listed as Variant/Variant(1 to 2)

Comment: So you'd need something like `If MFA(1) = "culstop" Then` depending on which slot has the value of interest

Comment: That worked! no idea why it stores the data that way but thank you!